# Shell: How to "reroute" matching input lines to a different file descriptor (STDOUT, STDERR)?

Tags: shell, pipe

I have to use an application that does not behave well: Informational messages are given on STDOUT, Error messages are also given on STDOUT, warnings on STDERR (yes, that really exists!).

Is there a simpler way to "reroute" specific, matching lines from STDOUT to STDERR (and vice versa) without extensive use of "tee" like this:

```
{ bad_application | tee /dev/fd/3 | grep ^Error: >&2 ;} 3>&1 | grep -v ^Error:
```

Any idea for a more straightforward solution that reduces the use of additional utilities and can do without the duplication (as this mixes up the sequence of the lines)?

Thanks,

Mazze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to affect order a bit but it should just move the error lines to standard output.

```
bad_application | awk '/^Error:/ {print > "/dev/stderr"; next} 7'
```

(7 is just a truth-y value to get the default `awk` action of `{print}`.)

If warning lines are marked the way error lines are marked you could toss everything to `awk` and avoid (at least somewhat) the output order mangling

```
bad_application 2>&1 | awk '/^(Error|Warning):/ {print > "/dev/stderr"; next} 7'
```

Comment: Thank you for the best answer so far :)
To make it more complicated or "perfect":
*) I would very much like order to be kept, 
*) I wanted Warnings on STDOUT instead of STDERR, and 
*) Other output from STDOUT and STDERR I wanted to stay there where it came from.
Maybe you can find a way around all that ... that would be so great for me, not matter, if it would be complicated.

Comment: Warning to `stdout` is easy. Just add `2>&1` to the first command. Ordering to a given output stream should be consistent but ordering between the output streams (if individually sent to the same location) may not be. The problem is that buffering differs (or can) between `stdout` and `stderr` so you'd need to deal with that to ensure that output between them both is handled in exactly sequential order... I think.

Comment: Both of the above snippets keep everything *not* `Error` sent to `stdout` on `stdout`. The latter moves everything from `stderr` (but `Warning`) to `stdout` that's true. You could, with some extra processing, keep things where they were originally (something like `{ bad_application | awk '!/^Error:/ {print "STDOUT:"$0; next} 7'; } 2>&1 | awk '/^STDOUT:/ {print substr($0,8); next} {print > "/dev/stderr"}'` or something like that (entirely untested and written in the comment box).

Comment: It might not be perfect yet (output line order), but it clearly answers my question and _is_ useful to me. Thank you!